# How do I change the fill color of the lightning checkbox-toggle?

Tags: lightning, checkbox

The fill color of the https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/checkbox-toggle/ toggle in the off position should not be grey. In UI design, greyed out means the toggle itself is disabled and can't be selected. The toggle in the off position is selectable and should be a color that doesn't look disabled. The iPhone toggle, for example, uses a white fill color, not grey.

Is it possible, and if so how, to change the fill color of the off position? It's flat out bad UI design. Has anyone seen this being talked about elsewhere? I'd like to give me feedback as well as track if they intend to correct their faux pas. Does anyone know how/where to give feedback to Salesforce about this toggle? Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the community. I will recommend to read this [article](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_css.htm) .

```
<div class="slds-form-element">
        <label class="slds-checkbox_toggle slds-grid">
            <span class="slds-form-element__label slds-m-bottom_none">Toggle Label</span>
            <input name="checkbox-toggle-5" type="checkbox" aria-describedby="checkbox-toggle-5" value="checkbox-toggle-5" />
            <span id="checkbox-toggle-5" class="slds-checkbox_faux_container" aria-live="assertive">
                <span class="slds-checkbox_faux"></span>
                <span class="slds-checkbox_on">Enabled</span>
                <span class="slds-checkbox_off">Disabled</span>
            </span>
        </label>
    </div>
```

Then go t the Style section to override the app.css [Salesforce default style] as per your need

```
.THIS .slds-checkbox_faux {
    background-color: cyan !important;
}
```